# ReactJS: How to render a collection of objects

Tags: reactjs

So I'm quite new on web development last couple of days. I come from c++ background and I can't wrap my head through all the principles of reactjs. I have 2 classes. The child class called JobAd should render some information that it got from props.

```
export default class JobAd extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            index: props.index,
            id: props.jobId,
            name: props.name,
            description: props.description,
            location: props.location,
            adress: props.adress,
            alreadyApplied: props.alreadyApplied,
            open: false,
           // toggleJob: props.toggleJob,
        };
        this.toggleJob = props.toggleJob;
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`${styles.jobAd} d-flex` + "job " + (this.state.open ? 'open': '')} key={this.state.index} onClick={() => this.toggleJob(this.state.index)}>
                <div className={`${styles.jobTitle}`}>
                   {this.state.location} - {this.state.name}  
                </div>
                <div className={`${styles.jobDetails}`}>
                    <div className={`${styles.jobDescription}`}> {this.state.description}</div>
                    <div className={`${styles.jobAdress}`}>{this.state.adress}</div>
                    <ApplyButton jobId= {this.props.id} alreadyApplied = {this.props.alreadyApplied}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The second class, queries a mongoDB db and creates jobAd objects populating them from the info gotten from db.

```
class JobExplorer extends React.Component
{
...

result.data.jobs.forEach(job => {
              var find = job.employees.find(obj => obj === userId);

              if (!(find === undefined)) {
                alreadyApplied = true;
              }


              var toPush = new JobAd  ({
                index: i,
                id:job._id,
                description:job.description,
                name:job.name,
                location:job.locationName,
                adress:job.locationAdress,
                alreadyApplied:alreadyApplied,
                open:false,
                toggleJob: this.toggleJob.bind(this)
              });
              jobList2.push(toPush);
              console.log("look");
              console.log(jobList2) 
              });
             
            
            this.setState({
              jobList: jobList2
            })


            this.setState({
              error: null,
              jobs: result.data.jobs
            });
...

render()
      {
              console.log("look2");
        
        console.log(this.state.jobList);
        return (
          <div><Navigation /> 
                                        {this.state.jobList}
          </div>
          );
      }
```

But I am faced with the following error which I cannot find a fix for.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, state, toggleJob}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How should I instantiate those objects so I could render them using the "architecture" I wrote. Is there a fundamental flaw that I have in my classes?

Comment: You might want to refer to react documentation to know how to render lists, see: [React - Lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet doesn't work because `new` will return an `object (this)` not the react component.

So, instead of

```js
var toPush = new JobAd({
    index: i,
    id: job._id,
    ...
});
jobList2.push(toPush);
```

you can do this

```js
var toPush = <JobAd
    index={i}
    id={job._id}
    ...
/>;
```

The above snippet works because  `<JobAd ... />` is converted to `React.createElement(JobAd, ... )`. However, you still shouldn't do it like this. since there are a lot of better ways to do this. one of them is:

save just the data in `joblist` and then render the data list on `JobAd` component

like below:-

```js
render(){
    return this.state.joblist.map((job, i) => (
        <JobAd
            key={job._id}
            index={i}
            ...
        />
    ));
}
```

The key is a really important thing. Read about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Things that could be improved:-

1. Don't copy props in the state as you are doing in `JobAd` class instead directly render the props.
2. Don't call setState twice as in `JobExplorer`. you could set all the keys in
   `setState` at the same time. since that would render the component twice.

Suggestions:-

1. You should avoid using `var` as that might cause some issues here.
2. since, you are just a starter, try using functional component first. they are
   quite easier to grasp

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misconception about state/props in React and web development. It's very normal; I learned python and Java first and many tutorials seem to assume that people just know this already.

"State" in generally refers to variables containing/referring to values that **can change without a page refresh in your application**. If you know a value is not going to change, it does not need to be held in state. Storing it in a normal variable is exactly what you should do.

"Props" is just another word for arguments that are passed to React components. There's more to it in reality, but as a beginner, that's all you need to really know for now.

So in your job add, things like name, address, jobs, description shouldn't go in state because they aren't going to change as a result of user interaction or for any other reason, unless the underlying data they are loaded from changes, but then that wouldn't be handled by React but instead by the API that your app gets data from. They should just be rendered, so refer to them like this.props.address in your render method. The value for open, however, need to be in state, because that definitely can change.

As for the error, it looks like you are not calling JobAd correctly. You need to use the syntax `<Job Ad/>` rather than `new JobAd`...that won't work in React.

I would recommend doing a tutorial to get the basics down.